# What's the sentence pattern of passive voice?

Tags: passive-voice

> We **saw** him enter the room. He **was seen** to enter the room.

When the sentence that has the pattern of “S+V+O+OC” is changed into passive form, do we call ‘to enter the room’ as a *subjective complement* or an *object*?

Comment: Most certainly not a [compliment](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/compliment).

Comment: @RegDwighт: I get the same feeling with you, but my Korean version of grammar books say they are subjective complements. So I need some authoritative source for this to persuade myself which is right or more persuasive. : Oh, now, I get what you pointed out, I corrected. Thank you.

Comment: I await a grammarian; but as the second sentence doesn't have an object surely it can't have an object complement.

Comment: OK, I'll be around in a bit. This is B-Raising followed by Passive on the next cycle, iyi.

Comment: It's long and no doubt overtypographed, but it would be a **lot** longer if I had to explain everything. Again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two sentences under question are

- *We saw him enter the room.*
- *He was seen to enter the room.*

The second is clearly the passive transform of the first. The problem is what to do with the infinitive [complement](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/aue/complmnt.html), complicated by where the *to* came from (or went to, if one uses a different model). As usual, a great deal has been deleted and modified already in that first sentence. Where did ***it*** come from?

As I mentioned in the comment, that first sentence is the result of **[B-Raising](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)**, followed by Passive.

> If you don't understand right away what I mean by *Raising* (never mind **A-** or **B-**), you can take a look at the link. It's some explanation, with examples, and a couple of solved problems. This is real English syntax, and it's likely to be strange; sorry about that. Strange people like me and my students think it's interesting.
> Or you can try to make sense out of what follows. Or, preferably, both.

The sense verb *see* governs B-Raising, which requires an infinitive object complement clause for *see*, roughly -- pre-deletions -

- *We saw* `[[for him] [to enter [the room]]]`

The infinitive object clause [S] has inner bracketings for the subject [NP] of the infinitive clause and the [infinitive verb phrase](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/VPguide.pdf) [VP] of the clause -- which contains a direct object NP. Both the subject NP and the VP are marked by complementizers (respectively, *for NP* and *to VP*). I.e,

- **We saw for him to enter the room.*

  > Of course that's not grammatical. Yet. Because all the required rules haven't applied. Yet. Intermediate structures with complex rule interactions are often ungrammatical. But like imaginary numbers, they're useful and they never really occur, so it's OK.

*See* is a sense verb and therefore occurs in a lot of idioms and metaphors. Mostly they involve making reference to metaphors, like *I see what you mean*. And most of them involve  chopping out chunks of clauses ("clause reduction" as it's called in the trade; see [Jim McCawley's](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf) famous paper "On Examining the Remains of Deceased Clauses").

It is normal for the subject complementizer *for* to be deleted, unless the infinitive is at the beginning of a sentence.

- *I want him to win the trophy.*
- *%I want for him to win the trophy.*
- *For him to speculate would be premature.*
- **Him to speculate would be premature.*

  > This is especially true when the subject gets deleted with Equi. So the *for* in `[for him]` is normally lost -- just remember that complementizers can surface again, in different constructions, and different dialects; this is where *for to see my Pollyanna* comes from.

Another of the peculiarities of sense verbs is that they don't allow *to* with an
infinitive complement.

- **We saw him to enter the room.*
- *We saw him enter the room.*

So **both** of the complementizers are deleted, leaving only the bracketing

- *We saw [[him] [enter the room]]*

That's still a direct object clause. What [Raising](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf) does, when it's governed by a Raising verb like *see*, is to change the bracketings, freeing the [him] to be the new Object of see, with the infinitive clause, now demoted to a phrase (*en chômage*, in Relational Grammar terminology), left right where it is at the end.

- *We saw [him] [enter the room].*

Now Passive applies to this Raised object *him*, producing

- [He] was seen [**to** enter the room].

**Except** that the passive of *see* doesn't have **quite** the same affordances as the active -- as I said, sense verbs are **complicated** -- and so the passive *seen* still requires the ordinary *to* complementizer. Which is automatically provided, free of charge, like the *do* of *Do*-support, from That Big Bag Of Auxiliaries In The Sky.

> P.S. Linear structure mashups like *“S+V+O+OC”* are very idiosyncratic, are not good representations of what's really going on, don't contribute much information, and therefore probably are not the best way to search for information. Syntax is constructions and rules.